# Free a struct in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

This is the node struct:

```
typedef struct addressBookNode
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    AddressBookArray * array;
    struct addressBookNode * previousNode;
    struct addressBookNode * nextNode;
} AddressBookNode;
```

My question is that when I free the node the node does not return NULL and instead id returns random memory values so is there a way to use free(node) for AddressBookNode * node which will make the node NULL?

Comment: The easiest way to do it in C will be to have a function `Free(AddressBookNode *)` which will call `free` and then set the value to `null`.

Comment: *is there a way* Yes. `free(node); node = NULL;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *dangling pointer*.  Calling `free` only releases the memory, but leaves your pointer intact.  It can't change your pointer, because you passed it *by value*.  Accessing that memory after releasing it is *undefined behavior*.

The correct approach is to set your pointer to NULL after calling `free`.  And then never attempt to follow a NULL pointer.

Don't write special functions or macros that roll the *free-then-set-null* paradigm into a single call.  That's just lazy, and only serves to hide information from the programmer.  Having worked on large commercial projects that do this, I can say it's a total pain in the butt.

So just get in the habit of setting your pointer to NULL explicitly, if you need it to be NULL.